# How to nab the golden idol on Spelunky Classic in Temple?

Tags: spelunky

On the Temple Level of Spelunky Classic there is a "Prayers to Kali" level feeling where there is a damsel and an idol suspended over lava by a thin bridge. If you try to take the idol the floor falls out and you almost certainly die or lose substantial health. Is there any way to safely nab the idols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to avoid this trap. If you have a parachute, climbing gloves, a cape, or a jetpack, you can stop your fall and climb back up. Another way, more likely to be available, is to set up a climbing rope beforehand. If you are quick, you can grab the rope as soon as you pick up the idol, and avoid falling.